# Gorilla Websocket example hangs when trying to send data to a channel whilst handling another channel?

Tags: go, websocket, channel, gorilla

I was following the chat client/server example for the gorilla websocket library.

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/hub.go#L36

I tried modifying the code to notify other clients when a new client connects, like so:

```
    for {
        select {
        case client := <-h.register:
            h.clients[client] = true

            // My addition. Hangs after this (no further register/unregister events are processed):
            h.broadcast <- []byte("Another client connected!")
        case client := <-h.unregister:
            if _, ok := h.clients[client]; ok {
                delete(h.clients, client)
                close(client.send)
            }
        case message := <-h.broadcast:
            for client := range h.clients {
                select {
                case client.send <- message:
                default:
                    close(client.send)
                    delete(h.clients, client)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is on the next iteration of the outer `for` loop, the broadcast channel should receive that data and follow the logic in the `message` case, but it just hangs.

Why? I can't spot any reason. No further channel events are processed (nothing on register/unregister or broadcast), which makes me think it's some kind of unbuffered channel mechanism it's stuck on, but I don't see how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hub's `broadcast` channel is unbuffered. Communication on an unbuffered channel waits for a ready sender and a ready receiver. The hub goroutine blocks because the goroutine cannot be ready to send and receive at the same time.

Changing the channel from an unbuffered channel to a buffered channel does not fix the problem. Consider the case where the buffer capacity is one:

```
return &Hub{
    broadcast:  make(chan []byte, 1),
    ...
}
```

with this timeline:

```
1 clientA: client.hub.register <- client 
2 clientB: c.hub.broadcast <- message
3 hub:     case client := <-h.register:
4 hub:     h.broadcast <- []byte("Another client connected!")
```

The hub blocks at #4 because the channel was filled to capacity at #2.  Increasing the channel capacity to two or more does not fix the problem because any number of clients can broadcast a message while another client is registering.

To fix the problem, move the broadcast code to a function and call that function from both cases in the select:

```
// sendAll sends message to all registered clients.
// This method must only be called by Hub.run.
func (h *Hub) sendAll(message []byte) {
    for client := range h.clients {
        select {
        case client.send <- message:
        default:
            close(client.send)
            delete(h.clients, client)
        }
    }
}

func (h *Hub) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case client := <-h.register:
            h.clients[client] = true
            h.sendAll([]byte("Another client connected!"))
        case client := <-h.unregister:
            if _, ok := h.clients[client]; ok {
                delete(h.clients, client)
                close(client.send)
            }
        case message := <-h.broadcast:
            h.sendAll(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your channels are unbuffered, this means that each read/write blocks until an other goroutine performs the opposite operation on the same channel.

When you try to write to `h.broadcast` the goroutine stops, waiting for a reader.  But the same goroutine is supposed to act as a reader of this channel, which never happens because the goroutine is blocked by the write. Thus the program deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, this won't work. You cannot send/receive on the same unbuffered channel in the same go routine.

The line `h.broadcast <- []byte("Another client connected!")` blocks until another go routine pops off that queue. An easy solution is to make the `broadcast` channel have a length 1 buffer. `broadcast :=  make(chan []byte, 1)`

You can see it in this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JgbrQVwfqtI) example

```
    // c := make(chan int) <- This will hang
    c := make(chan int, 1)
    c <- 1
    fmt.Println(<-c)
```

Remove the length 1 buffer and the whole system deadlocks. One issue you can run into is if 2 clients register at the same time, then you can have the case where 2 items are trying to be stuffed into the `broadcast` channel, and we're back to the same problem with the unbuffered channel. You can avoid this and keep 1 go routine like so:

```
for {
    select { 
        case message := <-h.broadcast:
            // ...
        default:
    }

    select { // This select statement can only add 1 item to broadcast at most
        case client := <-h.register:
            // ...
            h.broadcast <- []byte("Another client connected!")
        }
    }
}
```

However, this will still break if another go routine is also adding to the `broadcast` channel. So I'd go with Cerise Limon's solution, or buffer the channel enough that other go routines won't ever fill the buffer.

Comment: Ah true, more than 1 client could connect at a time. you can still keep this 1 go routine though by just ensuring you always check broadcast before register, and ensuring only 1 register can trigger 1 broadcast. I'll update my answer to show what I mean